# How can I spin a docker cotainer per api call?

Tags: docker, ros, gazebo-simu

My teammates and I are working on a backend, which would provide ros gazebo simulation that is hosted online. Due to the fact that it is very hard to let several instance of ros running on the same machine, we have decided that we will have a container running for each instance of ros gazebo. However, it there any tool to orchestrate the containers (running, stopping)? It's not like kubernetes style of managing containers, but like I need to spin a container per api call. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to throw it out there: it shouldn't actually be hard to run multiple ros instances on a single machine. Bad idea, though? Probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl to consume Docker API. Reference's documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/#run-a-container

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"Image": "alpine", "Cmd": ["echo", "hello world"]}' \
  -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/containers/create
 curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/containers/1c6594faf5/start
 curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/containers/1c6594faf5/wait
 curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://localhost/v1.41/containers/1c6594faf5/logs?stdout=1"
```

Where v1.41 is the API version of Docker. To check what version you are running just execute `docker version`

This way you have to make these calls from the host executing the Docker process though. If you need to execute remote calls to the host, the only thing you can do is to write a small executable that exposes a web interface that you can use to call internal Docker API (https://docs.rs/docker-api/latest/docker_api/)

Comment: Be very very very careful if you try this!  If you have access to the Docker socket you can do anything you want by launching another container, including launching a container as root with a read-write bind mount of the host's `/etc` directory, for example.

Comment: Is there any way fix to this, like creating a new user in the system and give it priviliges?